# Grails how to perform unit test on exceptions

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spring-security

I am trying to test that the account expired exception.

```
def authfail() {
    String msg = ''
    def exception = session[WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION]

//        println("print exception: ${exception} | ${session} | ${springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()}")
    if (exception) {
        if (exception instanceof AccountExpiredException) {
            msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.expired')
        }
        else if (exception instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) {
            msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired')
        }
        else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.disabled')
        }
        else {
            msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.fail')
        }
    }

    if (springSecurityService.isAjax(request)) {
        render([error: msg] as JSON)
    }
    else {
        flash.message = msg
        redirect action: 'auth', params: params
    }
}
```

I tried writing the test case above before realising i was stuck as I have no idea how to trigger an expired login so that the unit test criteria of having the AccountExceptionExpired exception thrown be fulfilled.

```
void "test authFail"() {

when:
    session."${WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}" = new AccountExpiredException( 'This account has expired' )
    def logexp = controller.authfail()
then:
    logexp == 'springSecurity.errors.login.expired'
when:
    session."${WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}" = new CredentialsExpiredException( 'This credentials have expired' )
    def passexp = controller.authfail()
then:
    passexp == 'springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired'
when:
    session."${WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}" = new DisabledException( 'The account is disabled' )
    def logdis = controller.authfail()
then:
    logdis == 'springSecurity.errors.login.disabled'
when:
    session."${WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}" = new UnsupportedOperationException( 'Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password.' )
    def logfail = controller.authfail()
then:
    logfail == 'springSecurity.errors.login.fail'
when:
    controller.authfail()
then:
    1 * springSecurityService.isAjax( _ ) >> true
    controller.response.json == [error :'springSecurity.errors.login.fail']

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will test the majority of your method:

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.CredentialsExpiredException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException
import org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(YourController)
class YourControllerSpec extends Specification {

def springSecurityService = Mock( SpringSecurityService )

void setup() {
    controller.springSecurityService = springSecurityService
}

void "test authFail"() {
    given:
        session."${WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}" = new AccountExpiredException( 'This account has expired' )
    when:
        controller.authfail()
    then:
        flash.message == 'springSecurity.errors.login.expired'
    when:
        session."${WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}" = new CredentialsExpiredException( 'This credentials have expired' )
        controller.authfail()
    then:
        flash.message == 'springSecurity.errors.login.passwordExpired'
    when:
        session."${WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}" = new DisabledException( 'The account is disabled' )
        controller.authfail()
    then:
        flash.message == 'springSecurity.errors.login.disabled'
    when:
        session."${WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}" = new UnsupportedOperationException( 'Bad stuff' )
        controller.authfail()
    then:
        flash.message == 'springSecurity.errors.login.fail'
    when:
        controller.authfail()
    then:
        1 * springSecurityService.isAjax( _ ) >> true
        response.json == [error :'springSecurity.errors.login.fail']
}
}
```

The session is just a map to which we add a key of the string constant and a value of the exception.
For all tests bar the final one we're falling through to your final else block, in the final test we return true for `isAjax'.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got this result.

https://imgur.com/nuO1cX7

Comment: Are you returning `msg` from `authfail` as suggested?

Comment: Im extremely new to this actually. I only implemented your code and got that result which I dont quite understand anyways, why is res NULL when it was defined above as the controller already.

Comment: It should work without the explicit return of `msg` but it's at least easier to read the code with the explicit return, have you imported the classes `org.springframework.security.web.WebAttributes` and `org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountExpiredException` in your test class?

Comment: Yes, I have imported those 2, it wouldnt even run before i imported those

Comment: Difficult to say, I have your exact method and the exact test above working in my IDE, clearly there's something different, without seeing the project it's difficult to diagnose

Comment: I have edited my post to show the entire controller if that helps. Thanks for your help so far anyways!

Comment: As ever. the devil is in the detail, try to give all the info in the initial question, the updated answer covers most of your scenarios, there are a few more to test

Comment: It has indeed worked now and i realised why too. Do you happen to have any idea how i could test the Ajax check?

Comment: The test failed when put together, so i tried cutting out almost everything except the 1st IF check for AccountExpiredException and the Ajax request check outside of the first IF Loop. These exceptions when by itself works fine but I do not understand why it breaks when put together.

Comment: What's the reason for failure? Are you mocking `springSecurityService` in your setup for example?

Comment: I  merely followed your setup and nothing else. Your first 4 test works fine without the Ajax test, however when i added in the Ajax test, I will get this error https://imgur.com/a/teRmPRc The Ajax test on its own works fine after i manually state msg = message(code: 'springSecurity.errors.login.fail')

Comment: I've updated with the entire test class that works in my IDE

Answer (score 0):

While this is not Grails, it is SpringBoot 2.0.

If the failureHandler is exposed as a bean, one can just spy on it.

```
@SpyBean
AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
```

and simply verify that the exception has been thrown

```
Mockito.verify(failureHandler).onAuthenticationFailure(
    any(),
    any(),
    any(AccountExpiredException.class)
);
```

A simple [test](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/9f5903e5e2df732dd14baf16da034b42c73fe012/samples/bearer-token-filter-chain/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/SpyOnTheFailureHandlerTests.java?ts=4#L48-L68) can look like this:

```
@Test
public void accountExpired() throws Exception {
    doReturn(user
        .username("expired")
        .accountExpired(true)
        .build()
    ).when(userDetailsService).loadUserByUsername(any(String.class));
    mvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
            .param("username", "expired")
            .param("password", "password")
    )
        .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError())
        .andExpect(unauthenticated())
    ;
    Mockito.verify(failureHandler).onAuthenticationFailure(
        any(),
        any(),
        any(AccountExpiredException.class)
    );
}
```

All samples at https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/